# Conducting sphere with a cavity

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I have a conducting sphere which has a cavity in it. The cavity is not at the center of the sphere. If a charge $+q$ is placed inside the cavity (with the sphere remaining neutral as a whole), what would be the electric field at a point outside the sphere?

Would the answer change if the charge is moved to a different location within the cavity?

Would the answer depend on the location of the cavity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field would, strangely enough, be equal to that of a uniformly charged sphere of charge $q$. The placement and shape of the cavity doesn't change the field outside the sphere.

By using Gauss's law, we see that $$\oint \mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf a = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon _0}$$

Where $Q_{enc} = q -q +q  = q$

The point charge in the cavity will induce an equal and opposite charge on the cavity wall, canceling out the contribution of the point charge outside the sphere, while the sphere must now take on a uniformly distributed charge of $q$, since the sphere is to remain neutral.

$\mathbf E$ inside the cavity depends on the geometry and position of the charge.

Answer (score 0):

A charge present inside the conducting cavity is not affected by any charge or electric field present outside the conducting sphere. This is a property called Electrostatic Shielding.

Now with regard to this property it does not matter where the cavity is or where t he charge is inside the cavity. Till the time it is in the cavity is does not experience any electric field due to external charges.

Now if we consider any arbitrary point C outside the sphere at a distance r then the electric field due to the charge +q will be Kq/r^2. Now since this charge is in the cavity it induces a charge -q on the inner surface of the cavity and the electric field due to this inner charge on C will be -Kq/r^2. Now as stated in the question the sphere is neutral to maintain this neutrality another charge +q develops on the outer surface of the sphere and the electric field due to this is again Kq/r^2. Now upon adding all the electric field the net electric field at a point C outside the sphere will be Kq/r^2.